# Python Password Refuses to be Validated

Tags: python, validation, passwords

My code refuses to validate the entered username and password even when entered correctly.

Code included below; have I gone wrong anywhere? If so, could you please tell me where?

Cheers.

```
import time

print ("Before playing, you must register.")
time.sleep(1)
username = open("username.txt","w+")
password = open("password.txt","w+")

print ("Please enter your desired username.")
username_input = input("> ")
print ("Please enter your desired password.")
password_input = input("> ")

username.write(username_input)
password.write(password_input)
username.close()
password.close()

time.sleep(1)
print ("Now, we must authenticate your username and password.")
time.sleep(0.5)
print ("Please input your username.")
u_input = input ('> ')
print ("Please input your password.")
p_input = input ('> ')
username.open("username.txt","r")
password.open("password.txt","r")
u_contents = username.read()
p_contents = password.read()
if u_input == u_contents:
  print ("Username authenticated.")

if p_input == p_contents:
  print ("Password authenticated.")

else:
  print ("Incorrect username or password.")

username.close()
password.close()
```

Comment: `.read()` reads the entire file, including newlines.  As a side-note: never store user credentials in a plaintext file like you're obviously doing.

Comment: You should `close()` your file and then reread it to access its content.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No newlines were written to the file.  The problem is the output hasn't been written to the file yet.

Comment: @JohnGordon missed that. Good call.  I'd suggest the OP learn the `with` keyword

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it's just for school, not a real thing :)

Comment: @Frankie See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: As it has already been pointed out, please learn to use context managers, i.e. "with" for handling any connection that needs to be closed. Also, loot at using getpass for the password (obfuscates the pword on the screen). Once again, it has been pointed out, dont store password plaintext, create a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you called `write()`, the contents haven't actually been written yet.  File contents aren't written to disk until the file is closed (or flushed) or the program exits.

Close the files after writing them.

Comment: I'm now getting this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
        username.open(username.txt,"r")
    AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: `username` is already an open file; you should be calling `username.close()` to close the file.

Comment: I've already closed it (I inserted close right after write); it's when i try to open it again

Comment: Edit your question to show your updated code.  It's hard to tell from short comments exactly what you changed.

Comment: Edited; should be up there now

Comment: `username.open(username,"r")` is not the right way to open the file.  Use `username = open("username.txt","r")` instead.

Comment: I just tried that before. I got the same error.

Comment: Your posted code shows `username.open(username,"r")`, which is an error.

Comment: I tried your suggestion before making the edit which is posted.

Comment: Edit the code to show what else you tried.  I can't debug code that I can't see.

Comment: Done. See if it's there now.

Comment: I still see `username.open("username.txt","r")`, which is an error.

Comment: OHHH I SEE THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `w+` is not working. I am posting the fully working code which I have changed yours. It is always useful to use `with/as` with `open()`import time

```
import time

print ("Before playing, you must register.")
time.sleep(1)

print ("Please enter your desired username.")
username_input = input("> ")

print ("Please enter your desired password.")
password_input = input("> ")

with open('username.txt', 'w') as u:
        u.write(username_input)
        u.flush()
        u.close()

with open('password.txt', 'w') as p:
    p.write(password_input)
    p.flush()
    p.close()

time.sleep(1)
print ("Now, we must authenticate your username and password.")
time.sleep(0.5)
print ("Please input your username.")
u_input = input ('> ')
print ("Please input your password.")
p_input = input ('> ')

username=''
password=''
with open('xx.txt', 'r') as u:
        username = u.read()
        u.close()

with open('xxx.txt', 'r') as p:
    password = p.read()
    p.close()

if u_input == username:
  print ("Username authenticated.")

if p_input == password:
  print ("Password authenticated.")

else:
  print ("Incorrect username or password.")
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Before playing, you must register.
Please enter your desired username.
> mike
Please enter your desired password.
> mike123
Now, we must authenticate your username and password.
Please input your username.
> mike
Please input your password.
> mike123
Username authenticated.
Password authenticated.
```